# Add space between time and PM/AM in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, parsing, time, formatting, formula

I have a spreadsheet with a couple hundred rows. Two of the columns contain times. There are 4 different possibilities for what the times can look like. The numbers can be anything, this is to demonstrate the spacing issues between the time and am/pm

```
1:30PM
4:30 PM
11:30AM
9:30 AM
```

Is there a way I can have excel automatically put a space if there isn't one, and not do anything if there is, so the above list would look like the following

```
1:30 PM
4:30 PM
11:30 AM
9:30 AM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is AM/PM in the actual value of the cell, or has it been added to the end as a result of the cell formatting?

If it is in the cell value, insert a column and try:

```
=IF( OR(RIGHT(A1,3) = " PM",RIGHT(A1,3) = " AM"),A1, CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)," ",RIGHT(A1,2)))
```

and drag down.

Comment: It's in the actual cell. The lack of space is due to user error

Answer (score 2):

Press Ctrl-H

Replace PM with (space) PM and AM with (space) AM.

Comment: Wouldn't that put a double space for those that already have a space?

Answer (score -1):

Just use find and replace... 
Search for "AM" Replace with " AM" Then do the same thing for PM...

Comment: It can end up with double space between AM and PM. Its also not a correct formating.